# How to run multiple functions based on specific time in Windows Service C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service project in Visual Studio 2015, in that i have multiple functions in a class that is to be executed on a specific time (for ex. first function at 11 AM, another at 11.15 and so on). But once i run the service only the first function gets executed as it meets the time but how can i execute the rest of the functions? Also is there any possibility that the service can run in background continuously?

Following is the code:

```
    public static void Process()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 16)
        {
            Function1("Time1");
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 17)
        {
            Function1("Time2");
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 18)
        {
            Function1("Time3");
        }
    }

    private static void Function1(string message)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        string file = "TestTimeService.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.Create(file);
        }
        File.AppendAllText(file, Environment.NewLine + "[" + DateTime.Now + "]: " + message);
    }
```

Comment: Its probably your code. Not much else we can help with there unless you show what you are doing. Also, the most reliable way to run scheduled tasks is with a scheduling framework, there are many

Comment: _"Also is there any possibility that the service can run in background continuously?"_ That's the point of a windows service. So if you actually do have a windows service project, then it is going to run continuously once it is deployed and installed and started.

Comment: I have made the changes and added the sample context in the post.